# Nuxt Env variables not working on Netlify

Tags: environment-variables, http-status-code-404, undefined, nuxt.js, netlify

I am trying to deploy to Netlify through github my static generated app made with Nuxt JS, and the issue I am having is with the API_KEY variable inside my .env file, even though I added them to the environement variables available on my Netlify Project Settings, I am still getting a 404 error and undefined api key on my app console log.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not, I switched to Heroku which is way easier to set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend use the env variables in your app (outside of the `nuxt.config.js`), then you might want to switch to [`runtimeConfig`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/runtime-config/).

```js
//nuxt.config.js
export default {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
  }
}
```

```js
//in your app
this.$config.baseURL
```

Comment: I have already done this, in fact here is my nuxt.config.js
proxy: {
    '/api/': { target: process.env.BASE_URL , pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' } }
    },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
      baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL
  },

  privateRuntimeConfig: {
      apiSecret: process.env.API_SECRET
  },

Comment: Have you tried to re-trigger a build after adding env variables on Netlify? :)

Comment: Yes I did, still nothing.

Comment: Please be aware that `privateRuntimeConfig` is only available during the build and *not after* (e.g. when navigating on client side).